# How to add multiple photos to a document?

Tags: graphics

I have been writing an article and have trouble addicting two aligned photos (the red ones in the picture below).

I would like it to look like this :

[image]

But for the moment, it looks like this :

[image]

I am using multiple folds in Overleaf and these are my folds :

**main.tex** :

```
\documentclass{rapport}
\input{Command and Packages}

\begin{document}

%----------- Informations du rapport ---------

\logo{logos/IRISA.png}
\titre{AAA} %Titre du fichier .pdf

\enseignant{AAA \textsc{BBB}} %Nom des élèves

\eleves{AAA \textsc{AAA} \\
        AAA \textsc{AAA} } %Nom des élèves

%----------- Initialisation -------------------
        
\fairemarges %Afficher les marges
\fairepagedegarde %Créer la page de garde
\tabledematieres %Créer la table de matières

%------------ Corps du rapport ----------------

\end{document}
```

**rapport.cls** :

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % Classe du document

%--------------------- Packages ------------------------


\RequirePackage[french]{babel} %Langue du document
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Caractères spéciaux
\RequirePackage[section]{placeins}%Pour placement de section
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} %Quelques lettres qui sont pas inclus dans UTF-8
\RequirePackage{mathtools} %Paquet pour des équations et symboles mathématiques
\RequirePackage{siunitx} %Pour écrire avec la notation scientifique (Ex.: \num{2e+9})
\RequirePackage{float} %Pour placement d'images
\RequirePackage{graphicx} %Paquet pour insérer des images
\RequirePackage[justification=centering]{caption} %Pour les légendes centralisées
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{wallpaper}
\RequirePackage{nomencl}
%\makenomenclature
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyheadoffset{1cm}
%\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%Paquet pour insérer légendes dans des sous-figures comme Figure 1a, 1b
\RequirePackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry} %Configuration de la page


%-------------------- Informations sur le rapport ----------------------

\newcommand{\cours}[1]{\renewcommand{\cours}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sujet}[1]{\renewcommand{\sujet}{#1}}
\newcommand{\titre}[1]{\renewcommand{\titre}{#1}}
\newcommand{\enseignant}[1]{\renewcommand{\enseignant}{#1}}
\newcommand{\eleves}[1]{\renewcommand{\eleves}{#1}}
\newcommand{\logo}[1]{\renewcommand{\logo}{#1}}
\newcommand{\unif}[1]{\renewcommand{\unif}{#1}}

\newcommand{\fairemarges}{
\makenomenclature
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset{1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{\logo}} %Affichage de l'image au top de la page
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
%\rfoot{\thepage}
%\cfoot{Rapport - \textbf{\titre}}
\lfoot{\cours}
}

\newcommand{\fairepagedegarde}{
\begin{titlepage}
\ThisLRCornerWallPaper{0.3}{logos/bordureLMU-lr.png}
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{0.3}{logos/bordureLMU-tl.png}
    \centering %Centraliser le contenu
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{\logo}\par\vspace{1cm} %Insertion du logo
    {\scshape\LARGE \unif \par} %Nom de l'université
    \vspace{1.5cm}%Espace de 1,5cm
    {\scshape\Large \cours \\ \sujet \\ \par} %sous-titre
    \vspace{1cm}%Espace de 1cm
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
    {\huge\bfseries \titre \par} \
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[1.5 cm]
    \vspace{1cm}%Espace de 1cm
    
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} %Minipage pour faire deux colonnes
        \begin{flushleft} \large %Envoyer à gauche
        \emph{\textbf{Encadrants :}}\\ %Pour le titre au dessus des noms à gauche
        \eleves\\ %Remplacer pour chacun
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    ~
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{\textbf{Stagiaire :}} \\
         \enseignant \\
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}\\[4cm]
    
    \vfill
    
\end{titlepage}
}

\newcommand{\tabledematieres}{
\tableofcontents
\newpage
}

\newcommand{\insererfigure}[4]{
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=#2]{#1}
\caption{#3}
\label{fig: #4}
\end{figure}
}
```

**logos**:

It contains the following pictures :

```
                                  bordureLMU-lr.png:
```

[image: bordureLMU-lr.png]

```
                                  bordureLMU-tl.png:
```

[image]

```
                                  IRISA.png:
```

[image]

```
                                 logo-entreprise.png:
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started:

**rapport.cls**

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % Classe du document

%--------------------- Packages ------------------------


\RequirePackage[french]{babel} %Langue du document
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Caractères spéciaux
\RequirePackage[section]{placeins}%Pour placement de section
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} %Quelques lettres qui sont pas inclus dans UTF-8
\RequirePackage{mathtools} %Paquet pour des équations et symboles mathématiques
\RequirePackage{siunitx} %Pour écrire avec la notation scientifique (Ex.: \num{2e+9})
\RequirePackage{float} %Pour placement d'images
\RequirePackage{graphicx} %Paquet pour insérer des images
\RequirePackage[justification=centering]{caption} %Pour les légendes centralisées
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{wallpaper}
\RequirePackage{nomencl}
%\makenomenclature
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyheadoffset{1cm}
%\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%Paquet pour insérer légendes dans des sous-figures comme Figure 1a, 1b
\RequirePackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry} %Configuration de la page


%-------------------- Informations sur le rapport ----------------------

\newcommand{\cours}[1]{\renewcommand{\cours}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sujet}[1]{\renewcommand{\sujet}{#1}}
\newcommand{\titre}[1]{\renewcommand{\titre}{#1}}
\newcommand{\enseignant}[1]{\renewcommand{\enseignant}{#1}}
\newcommand{\eleves}[1]{\renewcommand{\eleves}{#1}}
\newcommand{\logoL}[1]{\renewcommand{\logoL}{#1}}
\newcommand{\logoR}[1]{\renewcommand{\logoR}{#1}}
\newcommand{\unif}[1]{\renewcommand{\unif}{#1}}

\newcommand{\fairemarges}{
\makenomenclature
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset{1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{\logoL}} %Affichage de l'image au top de la page
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
%\rfoot{\thepage}
%\cfoot{Rapport - \textbf{\titre}}
\lfoot{\cours}
}

\newcommand{\fairepagedegarde}{
\begin{titlepage}
\ThisLRCornerWallPaper{0.3}{logos/bordureLMU-lr.png}
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{0.3}{logos/bordureLMU-tl.png}
    \centering %Centraliser le contenu
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{\logoL}\hspace{0.2\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{\logoR}\par\vspace{1cm} %Insertion du logo
    {\scshape\LARGE \unif \par} %Nom de l'université
    \vspace{1.5cm}%Espace de 1,5cm
    {\scshape\Large \cours \\ \sujet \\ \par} %sous-titre
    \vspace{1cm}%Espace de 1cm
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
    {\huge\bfseries \titre \par} \
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[1.5 cm]
    \vspace{1cm}%Espace de 1cm
    
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} %Minipage pour faire deux colonnes
        \begin{flushleft} \large %Envoyer à gauche
        \emph{\textbf{Encadrants :}}\\ %Pour le titre au dessus des noms à gauche
        \eleves\\ %Remplacer pour chacun
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    ~
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{\textbf{Stagiaire :}} \\
         \enseignant \\
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}\\[4cm]
    
    \vfill
    
\end{titlepage}
}

\newcommand{\tabledematieres}{
\tableofcontents
\newpage
}

\newcommand{\insererfigure}[4]{
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=#2]{#1}
\caption{#3}
\label{fig: #4}
\end{figure}
}
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{rapport}

\begin{document}

%----------- Informations du rapport ---------

\logoL{logos/IRISA.png}
\logoR{logos/logo-enterprise.png}
\titre{AAA} %Titre du fichier .pdf

\enseignant{AAA \textsc{BBB}} %Nom des élèves

\eleves{AAA \textsc{AAA} \\
        AAA \textsc{AAA} } %Nom des élèves

%----------- Initialisation -------------------
        
\fairemarges %Afficher les marges
\fairepagedegarde %Créer la page de garde
\tabledematieres %Créer la table de matières

%------------ Corps du rapport ----------------

\end{document}
```

#### Caveats

1. The two logos you provided have different font sizes and differing amounts of white-space. You may need to trim/resize them yourself using a graphics software to get them to be the right size relative to each other.
2. I think you uploaded the wrong file for `IRISA.png`; else you may want to change the file name to the one actually corresponding to the "desired output".
3. The class file you provided also tries to put a logo in the top left corner of the header. Your question however doesn't specify which logo you want there (or whether you wanted both). For now I default to just showing the logo on the left (the one defined by `\logoL`). You can play around with it as you see fit.